# Getting NULL Value out of Max(Date) if no Data exists in joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, maxdate

I want to see the latest approval date (V.Datum) of a certain item (BauteilID) coming from a distinct supplier (m.Lieferanz_FreigabeID). 
If there is not any approval date in the table related to a supplier, it should return NULL. Instead I get the latest approval date of other suppliers of the same item.

I tried to include `IsNULL` and `IF` conditions but it did not work.

```sql
    Select b.BauteilID, m.Lieferant_FreigabeID, Max(V.Datum) as Datum, m.Freigabe
    From WPLabor.dbo.MapBauteilStahlwerk m
    Join WPLabor.dbo.Bauteilspezifikation b  on b.BauteilID = m.BauteilID
    Join WPLabor.dbo.Verwendungsfreigabe v on v.BauteilID = b.BauteilID
    LEFT Join WPLabor.dbo.Stahlwerkzeugnis s on v.StahlwerkID = s.StahlwerkID And m.Stahlwerk = s. Stahlwerk
    group by b.BauteilID, m.Lieferant_FreigabeID, m.Freigabe
```

The result should be:

- ID1, Supplier1, Datum1, Freigabe1
- ID2, Supplier2, NULL, Freigabe2

Instead I get:

- ID1, Supplier1, Datum1, Freigabe1
- ID2, Supplier2, Datum1, Freigabe2

Help would by appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *If* all the values in the group are `NULL` then  `NULL` will be returned. This implies that your `GROUP BY` clause is wrong, or your `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be joining only on the Product ID and not the supplier and product which will result in returning the latest date of that product regardless of supplier.

Change:

```
Join WPLabor.dbo.Verwendungsfreigabe v on v.BauteilID = b.BauteilID
```

To something along the lines of:

```
Join WPLabor.dbo.Verwendungsfreigabe v on v.BauteilID = b.BauteilID AND v.SupplierID = b.SupplierID
```